# Stackoverflow design has changed on chrome but not on Opera or FF

Tags: support, stack-overflow, design

When I open stackoverflow with chrome, it looks as follows
 [image]

this is just on Chrome, but on Opera and FF it looks like it was before.
So what could be the problem?

Comment: You got yourself to the mobile theme. Go click "full site" in the footer.

Comment: @Oded that is it.